# Dynamically Adding Serialization Groups to Properties in Symfony 6.4 Using Traits

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 6.4 and have encountered a scenario where I need to dynamically assign serialization groups to entity properties defined in a trait. The goal is to use this trait across several entities (e.g., User, Profile) without losing the benefit of defining serialization groups directly within the trait's properties.

Each of my entities have their own Serialization Groups (User:read, User:write, User:read:collection, Profile:read...)

Here's the trait I'm using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Definition;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait LifeCycleTrait
{

    #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class)]
    #[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetimetz', options: ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'])]
    protected ?DateTime $createdAt = null;

    #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class)]
    #[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetimetz', options: ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'])]
    protected ?DateTime $updatedAt = null;
    ...
}
```

Currently, to assign serialization groups to these properties in implementing classes, I have to override them like so, which defeats the purpose of using the trait:

```
class User {
    use LifeCycleTrait;

    #[Groups(['User:read'])]
    #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class)]
    #[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetimetz')]
    protected ?DateTime $createdAt = null;

    #[Groups(['User:read'])]
    #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class)]
    #[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetimetz')]
    protected ?DateTime $updatedAt = null;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add serialization groups to these properties without having to override them in each implementing class. For context, I've successfully used the `loadClassMetadata` event for Doctrine to add field mappings manually for a Doctrine entity, but I'm unsure how to approach this for serialization groups.

Is there a way in Symfony, possibly using events or another mechanism, to dynamically assign serialization groups to trait properties during or before serialization?

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? Do you want to just make it reusable (like have 1 general file and then just append serialization groups based on which entity it is) or just make it totally dynamic meaning it would add all the serialization groups to each entity based on entity name?

If i understood correctly, you want just to not have to deal with serialization for 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' like fields for each entity...
As an idea, this might be possible with subscribing to 'onKernelView' event or making a decorator for api_platform.serializer.context_builder

Comment: @cile1993 i want to make it fully dynamic, not only for createdAt or updatedAt but for all traits i use for other properties.